# Create a list of hex codes given an Rgb range

Tags: python, string, list, hex, concatenation

I have these 3 vertices (end values) of `RGB` as `#ff0000`, `#ffcfcf` and `#350000` where `R` varies from `35` to `ff` , `G` from `00` to `cf` and `B` from `00` to `cf`. I need to create a list of all the possible values between them. I did the following:

```
import re
my_list=[]
for i in xrange(53,256):
    for j in xrange(0,208):
        for k in xrange(0,208):
            item = str(hex(i))+str(hex(j))+str(hex(k))
            item2 = re.sub('(0x)','',item)
            my_list.append(item2)
```

I iterated over the integer values and converted them to hex, followed by concatenating `RGB` values and replacing `0x` from the concatenated string(which doesn't work) . This method is quite slow. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a benchmark, I ran your code on my computer. It needed 27.8 s.

Regular expressions are always costly, so let's replace them by simple string replacement:

```
my_list=[]
for i in xrange(53,256):
    for j in xrange(0,208):
        for k in xrange(0,208):
            item = str(hex(i))+str(hex(j))+str(hex(k))
            item2 = item.replace("0x", "")
            my_list.append(item2)
```

This takes 8.8 s.

But all this *taking string representations of hexadecimal numbers and removing the `0x` in front of it* seems a bit *off* to me, especially since Python has built-in string formatting for that purpose:

```
my_list=[]
for i in xrange(53,256):
    for j in xrange(0,208):
        for k in xrange(0,208):
            my_list.append("{0:02x}{1:02x}{2:02x}".format(i,j,k))
```

This takes 8.3 s. A tiny bit better, but it also looks a bit cleaner. If we use [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product), we can even write this as a one-liner (sans long line break and import statement):

```
import itertools
my_list = ["{0:02x}{1:02x}{2:02x}".format(i,j,k) for i,j,k
           in itertools.product(xrange(53,256), xrange(0,208), xrange(0,208))]
```

This takes 8.1 s. Still not there.

Right now, the string formatting is the operation which costs most time. It is also an operation that we can avoid easily (since we're only ever formatting the same 256 values). Let's create a lookup table:

```
import itertools
m = ["{0:02x}".format(i) for i in xrange(256)]
my_list = [m[i] + m[j] + m[k] for i,j,k
        in itertools.product(xrange(53,256), xrange(0,208), xrange(0,208))]
```

Run time: 1.6 s. Hopefully fast enough.

Comment: Awesome , it works.. The last one should actually be assigned to a variable instead of return , right?? And could u explain what {0:02x} does?

Comment: @Swordy Yes, thanks, I've changed it. It was return before because I wrote all versions as functions to benchmark them. And the `{0:02x}` is a format string. You can read more about them [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax); the [examples on that page](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples) are especially useful for someone new to them. Basically, it says _"Take the first argument of the format method (0-based) and print it as a hex number (`x`), and put zeroes in front so it's at least 2 characters long (`02`)."_